# NSPopover loses first responder

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSPopover` in my application with various buttons. One button allows the user to tweet using the `NSSharingService`:

```
NSArray* array = @[ @"Tweet something"];
NSSharingService* sharingServiceFB = [NSSharingService  sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter];
    [sharingServiceFB performWithItems:array];
```

This works well, but when the tweet has been sent or cancelled, the focus is returned to the main application (main window) and not the `NSPopover`. How can I return focus to the `NSPopover`?

My initial approach was to observe `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification`which calls a method when notification has been received that does the following

```
if (self.sheetPopover!=nil){
    [self.sheetPopover becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

However, this did not work as expected and I still have to click twice on the `NSPopover` to regain focus. Any suggestions as to how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. I made my `NSPopover` a delegate of `NSSharingServiceDelegate`, and implemented two of the delegate methods where I reset the first responder when the twitter view had closed. Here, self is the `NSPopover` view.

```
- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didShareItems:(NSArray *)items
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [[self window] becomeKeyWindow];
    [[self window] becomeMainWindow];
```

}

```
- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didFailToShareItems:(nonnull NSArray *)items error:(nonnull NSError *)error
{
   [self becomeFirstResponder];
   [[self window] becomeKeyWindow];
   [[self window] becomeMainWindow];
}
```

Comments as to whether this is the best approach are very welcome.